# Requests hit using Jmeter missing Varnish cache but if Send using Postman it hit cache

Tags: jmeter

I am facing issue where i am sending one GET request using Jmeter. Response headers shows every time it miss Varnish cache on Server and response is returned from Application Sever. Please find below header 
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0

If i send exact same request using Postman, first time it miss Varnish cache but if i send same request again, it hits Varnish cache and cache hits counts increased. 
X-Cache → HIT
X-Cache-Hits → 1

I have tried Jmeter versions 2.6,2.9,2.11 and 2.13, but observed same behavior. Even when request is sent from Fiddler, i can see from header response is returned from Varnish Cache itself.

It just simple get request. I have compared JMeter and Postman request, both requests are exact same. Please let me know how i can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on when you wrote above, I can guess that:

1. All 1st requests are processed in the same way, doesn't matter how they were send.
2. As a part of response to your first request, server returns you a command to set up new header, in the same way as it process cookies (SET-COOKIE logic). So, server expects that your next request will contain this required X-Cache header.

But Jmeter is not a browser and doesn't correlate next request with  previously received data (by default at least). So, all is OK if you replay this scenario with browser (and its extensions). And your Jmeter sends the same request every time.

If you compare 1st and 2nd request sent by your browser, you'll find that your 2nd request contains required hearer.

So, if I'm right, to resolve the issue:

1. Identify the way how your server tells the client to add new header to next request (Javascript?)
2. Implement this logic in your Jmeter scenario.

Or just add X-Cache header to your request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try this on Monday and will update the thread with details.

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that Postman (whatever it is) respects [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) header while JMeter doesn't.

I believe adding [HTTP Cache Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have added unique key in header every time request goes top server and it started returning response from Varnish cache. Unique is random number.

i also checked Postman also send one unique parameter in each and every request. Though I am still not sure why unique is making difference here.